# Synchronization on AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, thread-synchronization

Consider I have a static website on S3 with a button <kbd>Register</kbd> in my website which calls an AWS Lambda function via API. I want that Lambda function to handle multiple requests sequentially, not concurrently. i.e, if it finishes the work for 1 request then only it will start working for other requests and so on and I will show on website that "Your request has been taken".

Comment: This does not sound like a good use case for Lambda. A queuing system (SQS, RabbitMQ, etc.) is a better fit.

Comment: Can you elaborate the reason for sequential execution?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note also that Lambda is limited to request/response or event behavior: in the request/response model, no response can be returned until the Lambda function has completed *all* of its work; in the event model, the Lambda function runs asynchronously from the caller's perspective, and no response can be provided other than whether the system accepted the request for processing, or not.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Just set lambda concurrency to 1